# asymptotics of the percentage point for $\chi^2_k$

Tags: statistics, asymptotics, chi-squared

For $k\geq 1$ let $T_k\sim \chi^2_k$.

For $a\in ]0,1[$ let us define $c_a(k) = \min \{ s\geq 0,  \mathbf P ( T_k \leq s )\geq a\}$.

Would anybody have a **free** reference for a study of the asymptotics of the sequence $(\ c_a(k)\ )_k$ ?

It looks like for $k\to+\infty$, it should begin with something like

$$c_a(k) = k + p(a) \sqrt k + o(\sqrt k)$$

I would already be happy to see a formula for $p(a)$, but the dominant term in the error $o(\sqrt k)$ is also of interest to me ...

Maybe the solution is written in [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2286208) but it is not free.

Comment: If you are looking for the asymptotics as $k \to \infty$ then note that the mean of $\chi^2_k$ is $k$ and variance is $2k$ with a central limit theorem type of behaviour

Comment: Thanks, I edited to make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Henry. The result is thus :

$$c_a(k)=k+z_a\sqrt{2k}+O(1)$$

where $z_a$ is defined by using $Y\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$ as

$$z_a=\min\{s≥0,\mathbf P(Y≤s)≥a\}$$

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).